# Lat Lon in TwitteR package producing NA

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to obtain lat + lon through the [TwitteR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) package, but the lat/lon columns of the resulting data frame are all NA.

```
tweets<-searchTwitter('cats',n=100)
tweets<-do.call("rbind",lapply(tweets,as.data.frame))
```

Is there any way around this, or is there another method to extract location data of tweets?

Comment: Very few tweets have location attached. When I was doing analysis on tweets a few years ago, it was under 10% for the data set I was looking at.

Comment: yeah you're right. Doing a bit of a workaround now, extracting location from actual users instead of tweets, then parsing against gdata to find lat lon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like lat/lon is not available for the tweets.

I can get location information from the users that composed the tweet. Inherent in TwitteR is the ability to do this:

```
a<-getUser("eastandwestwind")
a$location
[1] "Boston, MA"
```

So if I had a data frame with a screenName column, I could lapply a function that extracts location info over that column.

```
getLocation<-function(x){
    y<-getUser(x)
    return(y$location)
}

locations <- lapply(tweets$screenName, function(x) getLocation(x))
```

From here, I can attach the locations as a new column in the original data frame

```
tweets$city<-locations
```

Coerce back to data frame, since $city is a list

```
tweets<-data.frame(lapply(tweets, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```